# Compiling a C++ Win32 project as a .exe file under Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compilation

I have a C++ application that works and compile perfectly. I can execute and debug it via Visual Studio.
I would like to know how to compile to an .exe file. Actually under the debug dir there are only .obj file.

How to tell VS to compile it to a single .exe file ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you do a file search in the directory heirarchy that contains your solution and projects?  You should see the .exe in there.  VS won't debug without the .exe I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going from memory for the names, seeing as I'm on Fedora right now, but there's a `Build Project` option in one of the menus, I believe Tools. One of these will give you 2 checkboxes, one for debug, and one for release. Make sure the `Release` option is selected, and click `Build`. This will compile a standalone (as in, not needing the project) release version in your project directory, `projectName\bin\release` alongside your `debug` directory.

Comment: Actually it's in Build - Configuration manager, 

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Heh, yeah, I could remember the steps, and what the windows looked like, just not the names

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate folders for solution and project, the EXE would be in the Debug or Release folder under the solution folder. The one under project is for temporary build files only. You can override these paths in your project settings though.